# User Input - Date Range

Tags: vba, excel, user-interface

### Description

A new utility I built to ask users to input a date range (StartDate + EndDate).

Function **`AskDateRange()`** that handles loading/unloading the form and passing back input.

The userform itself, **`ufAskDateRange`**. Which validates that the user has entered text that looks like a date.

---

### Review Aims

These days, my focus is on ease-of-maintenance, so please critique accordingly.

If you saw this code in a legacy system, how would you be feeling?

---

### Calling the Function

```
    Public Sub TestAskDateRange()

        Dim startDate As Date
        Dim endDate As Date
        Dim result As Boolean

        result = AskDateRange(startDate, endDate, CDate("01/01/2017"), CDate("07/07/2018"))

    End Sub
```

---

### **`AskDateRange()`**

```
    Public Function AskDateRange(ByRef startDate As Date, ByRef endDate As Date, Optional ByVal defaultStartDate As Date, Optional ByVal defaultEndDate As Date) As Boolean

        '/  If default dates are supplied, insert them into the relevant textboxes
        '/  Show the ufAskDateRange Userform
        '/  Form handles user input

        '/  Check for form exit conditions
        '/  Returns TRUE if the form exited properly, FALSE otherwise
        '/  If TRUE, pass back inputs.
        '/  If FALSE, pass back 0-dates

        With ufAskDateRange

            '/ Set defaults
            If defaultStartDate > 0 Then .startDate = defaultStartDate
            If defaultEndDate > 0 Then .endDate = defaultEndDate

            .Show

            '/ Check for form Exit
            AskDateRange = .ValidExit
            If .ValidExit Then
                startDate = .startDate
                endDate = .endDate
            End If

        End With

        Unload ufAskDateRange

    End Function
```

---

### **`ufAskDateRange()`**

[image]

```
    Private pDateFormat As String
    Private pValidExit As Boolean

    Public Property Get ValidExit() As Boolean
        ValidExit = pValidExit
    End Property

    Public Property Get startDate() As Date
        startDate = CDate(txtStartDate.Text)
    End Property
    Public Property Let startDate(ByVal startDate As Date)
        txtStartDate.Text = startDate
    End Property

    Public Property Get endDate() As Date
        endDate = CDate(txtEndDate.Text)
    End Property
    Public Property Let endDate(ByVal endDate As Date)
        txtEndDate.Text = endDate
    End Property

    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

        '/ Determine system date format and update userform display
        Select Case Application.International(xlDateOrder)

            Case 0
                '/ Month-Day-Year
                pDateFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"

            Case 1
                '/ Day-Month-Year
                pDateFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"

            Case 2
                '/ Year-Month-Day
                pDateFormat = "YYYY/MM/DD"

        End Select

        lbStartDateFormat.Caption = pDateFormat
        lbEndDateFormat.Caption = pDateFormat

        '/ Set exit check
        pValidExit = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()

        '/ Clear Input Boxes
        txtStartDate.Text = ""
        txtEndDate.Text = ""

    End Sub

    Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

        '/ Try to force exit via the submit button
        If CloseMode = 0 Then
            cmdSubmitDates_Click
            Cancel = True
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdSubmitDates_Click()

        '/ Validate input boxes as dates. Require 10 digits to catch potential missing digits/mistyped dates
        If Not IsDate(txtStartDate.Text) Or Len(txtStartDate.Text) <> 10 Then
            MsgBox "Start Date is not in a recognised date format. Please input a new date"
            txtStartDate.SetFocus
            GoTo FailedValidation
        End If

        If Not IsDate(txtEndDate.Text) Or Len(txtEndDate.Text) <> 10 Then
            MsgBox "End Date is not in a recognised date format. Please input a new date"
            txtEndDate.SetFocus
            GoTo FailedValidation
        End If

        pValidExit = True
        Me.Hide

FailedValidation:
        Exit Sub '/ return focus to userform, having been prompted by the MsgBox

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu` instead of a hard-coded `0` in the `QueryClose` handler. Also...

> Order of date elements:
>
> 0 = month-day-year
>    1 = day-month-year
>    2 = year-month-day
>
> <sub>([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177675(v=office.12).aspx))</sub>

I think these magic values deserve their own constants / enum values:

```
'values returned by Application.International(xlDateOrder)
Public Enum xlDateOrderFormat
    MonthDayYear = 0
    DayMonthYear = 1
    YearMonthDay = 2
End Enum
```

And then this:

> ```
> Select Case Application.International(xlDateOrder)
>
>     Case 0
>         '/ Month-Day-Year
>         pDateFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
>
>     Case 1
>         '/ Day-Month-Year
>         pDateFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
>
>     Case 2
>         '/ Year-Month-Day
>         pDateFormat = "YYYY/MM/DD"
>
> End Select
> ```

Becomes:

```
Select Case Application.International(xlDateOrder)

    Case MonthDayYear
        pDateFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"

    Case DayMonthYear
        pDateFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"

    Case YearMonthDay
        pDateFormat = "YYYY/MM/DD"

End Select
```

Nitpick, I'd probably rename `AskDateRange` to `PromptDateRange`, and `ufAskDateRange` would be `DateRangePromptDialog` - not a fan of the Hungarian `uf` for `UserForm` here.

UX nitpick - I'm not a fan of popping `MsgBox` for something like input validation; it feels a bit clunky IMO. A *better* way would be to have <kbd>Ok</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd> buttons, and only enable <kbd>Ok</kbd> when the form is in a valid state, and perhaps have a label that's only visible in a non-empty and invalid state, to replace the `MsgBox` message. Something like this:

[image: better UX]

And now the review.

---

> ```
> Public Function AskDateRange(ByRef startDate As Date, ByRef endDate As Date, Optional ByVal defaultStartDate As Date, Optional ByVal defaultEndDate As Date) As Boolean
> ```

It took me a good 5 seconds to realize the two `ByRef` parameters were the returned values, and another 2 to realize that the `Boolean` return value actually means that *despite the input validation*, you're allowing the user to "submit" the form in an invalid state... wait no, you're not - the function can only ever return `True`, because `.ValidExit` can only be `True` if the form returned. Not intuitive.

With the UX I'm suggesting above, the form would have some `IsCancelled` state instead, set to `True` when the form is closed through either the control box (which you're disabling) or via the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button. Not allowing the user to cancel via the control box is also unintuitive UX: users are used to dismiss prompts by clicking that "X" button, and you're denying them that - a lot will be surprised by this behavior.

I'd change the signature to this:

```
Public Function PromptDateRange(ByRef outStartDate As Date, ByRef outEndDate As Date, Optional ByVal defaultStartDate As Date, Optional ByVal defaultEndDate As Date) As Boolean
```

So it could be used like:

```
Dim startDate As Date, endDate As Date
If PromptDateRange(startDate, endDate) Then
    'dates are valid
Else
    'dialog was cancelled, dates are irrelevant
End If
```

Notice how the `Boolean` result is now meaningful at the call site.

As for the function itself, I don't like how you're using the form's *default instance* - forms are classes, treat them as such!

```
With New DateRangePromptDialog

    If defaultStartDate <> CDate(0) Then .StartDate = defaultStartDate
    If defaultEndDate <> CDate(0) Then .EndDate = defaultEndDate

    .Show
    If Not .IsCancelled Then
        outStartDate = .StartDate
        outEndDate = .EndDate
    End If

    PromptDateRange = Not .IsCancelled

End With
```

With every call being made with a new instance, you no longer need to worry about state persisting between calls - thus I'd remove the `Class_Terminate` handler.

I would also handle the two textboxes' `Change` event, and validate there (to display/hide the `ValidationMessageLabel` and enable/disable the <kbd>Ok</kbd> button).

This leaves what I'd have as `AcceptButton_Click()` handler with no logic other than `Me.Hide` ...not commenting on that `GoTo`, you're trolling me :)

---

Note: the form validation logic should probably also ensure that `EndDate >= StartDate`, once both fields contain valid dates.

Comment: `...not commenting on that GoTo, you're trolling me :)` +1 for the whole answer but mostly this sentence